# Why Domain Redirection not working on mobile

Tags: redirect, dns

i am creating an adult content streaming website and i need domain redirection for my website because of the government regulations,

so briefly my main domain is banned from the country but accesible with vpn etc. so i set up a redirecment.

it works on desktop because the regulations not applied on desktop but on mobile it doesnt redirect

i'm thinking that it is not redirecting because the website is banned and to redirect firstly website needs to be opened

can you help?

i tried both 301 and 302 for redirectment, both doesnt work.